# How to get user's location from Google TV

Tags: google-tv

Is there a way to grab the lat and lon that corresponds to the zip code the user supplied when setting up their Google TV box?

Comment: I'm asking because I didn't see this in the documentation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a presentation by Christian Kurzke of Google at AnDevCon II, you use:

```
Location loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(“static”);
```

which will require the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission.